# How do I know if a Java class for a particular function exists?

Tags: java, api

I'm a new student to programming and taking my first introduction to Java college class.  Certain pre-made functions exist in Java such as `Math.pow(x, y);` or `System.out.println();` but how do I know what other ones are available for use?  Do you have some way of looking these up in the API documentation that I don't know?  I could browse that data all day and find nothing even close to what I'm trying to accomplish.  I wouldn't even know what package it was in.  I understand practice makes perfect, but it would be nice to know if something exists before I attempt to create it from scratch.

Comment: It's all right here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: Aside from looking into the links that everyone else has posted, I would recommend googling tutorials on "whatever you're trying to do" and getting an idea of how it works.  You can do just about anything, so you have to have some starting point. Are you working witha  database? trying to draw a circle? writing a web server? etc. etc. You need to have an objective and then just google "how do I ______ in Java". It will be a process of trial and error from there, but you'll definitely learn about the multitudes of libraries and APIs available to you.

Comment: Have a look at the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ If you know the import package the you could easily traverse through the API and find the classes and the different function. I guess this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html would also be of great use since you are learning. It would take you through the ups and downs of Java.

Comment: To everyone saying just look at the API docs - is that really sensible? If someone wanted to know if Java had a power function built in, do you really think the best thing to do is trawl through the Javadoc for every class?

Comment: @berry120, I agree completely. If you know what you're looking for that's a terrific resource. If you're just looking to get started with the language, you may as well be heading out to sea without a compas.

Comment: @berry120 Well searching for a "math" class would probably not be absurd when searching for a power function - i.e. often enough the classes are named sensibly enough that searching the jdocs really would work. But I agree, [google](https://www.google.at/search?q=java+power+function) is the way to go.. sadly one often gets ancient jdocs that way which then means another search *sigh* (and there I thought for that single query google would now probably link to the java7 jdocs, but no 1.4.2 - sometimes not even murphy is strong enough)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are if there's something you think someone else might want to do, there's a library around for it - either built into the JDK or as a 3rd party library.

The quickest way for any particular function you're after is just to Google, and you should find out whether it's in the JDK or available as a library pretty quickly. If that fails, then (non-duplicate) questions here asking if anyone knows a library with x functionality for Java are fine too.

Eventually, as you say, after a while you'll build up a pretty extensive knowledge of such common functionality - and that may well come quicker than you think.

Comment: Thanks for the honesty.  I guess I'm off to start practicing some arrays.